# Getting response after posting a JMS message

Tags: java, jms, response, message

The following block of code is used to post a set of JMS messages to an EMS server

```
            for(int i=1;i<=200;i++)
            {

                msg=myMessages.get(i); // myMessages is an Arraylist of TextMessages
                qsender = qsession.createSender((Queue)msg.getJMSDestination());
                qreceiver=qsession.createReceiver((Queue)msg.getJMSDestination());
                temp1 = qsession.createTemporaryQueue();
                responseConsumer = qsession.createConsumer(temp1);
                msg.setJMSReplyTo(temp1);
                msg.setJMSCorrelationID(msg.getJMSCorrelationID()+i);
                qsender.send(msg);

            }
```

Since this was not developed by me, I have some queries on it.

1. What does the query actually do? Does it just post the messages without a response?
2. If yes, how do we know when the response comes back and how do we calculate the time taken?
3. And how do we calculate the total time the message takes to reach there and the response to come back?

Please let me know if any more info is required.

Comment: If _"myMessages is an Arraylist of Strings"_, then _"`msg.setJMSReplyTo(temp1);`"_ does not compile.

Comment: @npe Updated. ArrayList of TextMessages.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it just post the messages without a response?

yes. it also creates a sender to send the message and a receiver which it doesn't appear to use.

> If yes, how do we know when the response comes back and how do we calculate the time taken?

It creates a temporary queue and a receiver for that. It expect the other end will send a message to the queue name stored in "JMSReplyTo"

> And how do we calculate the total time the message takes to reach there and the response to come back?

You can have the consumer get the time and match it to the time the first message was sent.

IMHO A simpler approach is to add the time sent as a property and have the service return this back. This way you have all the information you need in the message coming back.

Comment: Does it create a temporary Queue for every message? Is it advisable to have a single queue defined for it? Also do I set the property in the **msg**  ? How do we get the time when the response message comes back? Do we have to implement the MessageListener interface?

Comment: Its creating a temporary queue for every message. I would create one per session, but you may need to change other code for this to work. You can set and get properties on the message to pass on and read the initial timestamp. You should already have a `MessageListener` implementation.

Comment: Thanks. The code as of now doesn't have a MessageListener implementation. Since the tool's purpose was to just put messages in to the queue, I guess it was not required? Now that I need to get the response back I guess I have to implement it?

Comment: Also how do we "get" the properties on the message? This has to be done in the Listener if I am not wrong? If yes, then how do we identify the messages to calculate the start and end time? I know there are too many ques :-)

Comment: Haven't done it a while so a quick google found me; setLongProperty and getLongProperty. I would add the System.currentTimeMillis() or System.nanoTime(). Set the time before sending the message, have the responder send the same time in the reply, get the property in the listener and compare it to the current time.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions :

1. Yes, it only post messages ;
2. You do know when a message comes back by implementing a `MessageListener` then each times the `onMessage()` method is invoked a new message will be ready for processing ;
3. To answer the third question is a bit more complicated but you may want to log or write in some kind of persistent storage the time when the message was posted, and when the response was received (based on the correlationId, you may then be able to know how much time was elapse for each message) ;

Regards,

Y.

Comment: @Y but then msg would be different in diff iterations yea? how can pull it out of the loop as given in the code by you?

Comment: Yes, I've answered too quickly and didn't see that the destination was message-dependent, sorry for that, I've edited my post.